# ASP.NET Page freezes/hangs after GridView is displayed

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, freeze, linkbutton

I have a GridView which is displaying about 1000 rows.
Each recordset has only two columns so the loading of the records is not the problem maybe.

After the GridView has finished the binding and Page_LoadComplete also has finished, the data of the GridView will be displayed on the website.

But after the page is displayed for like 2 seconds and i try to scroll down, the website freezes for about 10 seconds.

I think it has to do with the fact that i only display LinkButtons in the GridView.

Is it just the browser which has problems with displaying a huge amount of the buttons or is there any way to solve a problem like this?

I also tried to display the LinkButtons without a GridView (just a table with rows a column and a hyperlink) and i had the same problem, so it's probably not the GridView I guess.

I hope someone can help me cause i did'nt find any solution so far.

Comment: Which browser are we talking about ? Older versions (of IE) might indeed be slow at rendering a lot of HTML. If this occurs on all browsers, chrome (and probably others) has a profiling tool that might help seeing where the bottleneck is. As such it is hard to point to a specific cause.

Comment: No i use the current IE. But it happens on all browsers. Has IE a build in profiling tool or do you know any good one?

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the maxRequestLength in you webconfig?  I'm not positive that will help, but worth a shot if you haven't tried.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using **Paging** concept? It is better to have paging enabled when you have more than 100 rows of data to be displayed on the page.

Having more rows in your grid (even if you have less number of columns) results in browser taking time to render it.

Comment: Usually i do yes. But in that case it is important to have it without paging. I need to display all data.

Comment: Try adding HTTP Compression and URL compression in your Web.config. More information is here : http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpcompression